# Protractor File Upload to a Link

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, automated-tests

I'm trying to upload a file using protractor and typescript. The upload button is on a toolbar that holds two other buttons as well. Unlike many of the examples I saw here, this upload button is implemented as a link and not an input.There is this warning in the console. There is no error, but the file isn't getting uploaded.

Warning below:

```
more than one element found for locator By(css selector, a.mat-icon-button) - the first result will be used
```

HTML below :

[image: HTML of the toolbar div]

This is how I am trying to upload the file.

```
    const fileToUpload = './Test_file.xlsx';
    const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    const uploadlink = element(by.css('a.mat-icon-button'));
    uploadlink .sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Comment: You should invoke `sendKeys()` on `input` element. Is there any `input` element? What happans when you click `uploadlink` element?

Comment: There is no input element in the html. When I click the link it opens up a window to select the file to be uploaded. I am not sure how this is implemented. but as you can see from the html. there is no input element there.

Comment: @njosep, could you click the button manually, upload the file by selecting the file and then check the html? Share the html post manual upload before submitting the page

Answer (score 0):

In that situation, if you are working in the Windows environment, I recommend looking into AutoIT.

It's very simple to script and use.

https://www.autoitscript.com/site/

Answer (score 0):

> more than one element found for locator By(css selector,
>   a.mat-icon-button) - the first result will be used

If you have 3 elements, and 3rd one is the element that handles upload, other 2 are just a link ref ?

Try to write more specific locator to the "upload" a tag.

can you verify on clicking of the button, if an input is present inside the code?

If there is no other solution use AutoIt.

Answer (score 0):

```
   const fileToUpload = './Test_file.xlsx';
    const absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
    const uploadlink = element(by.css('a.mat-icon-button>span.mat-button-wrapper>div.command-text'));
    uploadlink .sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

If the above doesn't help try javascript executer
https://blog.ng-book.com/executing-raw-javascript-in-protractor/

Comment: That failed with error - Failed: unknown error: cannot focus element (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)

Comment: Try adding some sleep before uploading the file